# Magento 2 Automated Returns

Tags: return, magento2

I am looking for a tool that can be easily integrated into Magento 2. This should enable me, or rather my customers, to register automatic returns, just like you know it from the big marketplaces: The customer sees his order and can select products that he wants to return and automatically receives the return label by email after confirmation. It should also be possible to connect the system to the logistics department so that it can process incoming returns directly.

I hope my information makes sense, I am not from the DEV area, but am a beginner with a sales background

**Can you recommend a plugin/software/provider that you have had good experiences with?**

Cheers!

This is the first try, so we haven't tested any tool yet, as this is new for us.

Comment: Hello, this feature (named RMA) is part of the Magento Enterprise Edition, or rather now Adobe Commerce. As it's name suggests it's the paid version of Magento. It does not however connect to logistics.